# primefaces commandButton "update" not working

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

**I have this dialog:**

```
    <p:dialog 
        id="dlgComment"
        widgetVar="dialogComentario"
        modal="true"
        header="#{messages.comentarios}"
        width="600px"
        resizable="false" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip">
        <h:form id="formComentario">
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 100%">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{monitorarEventoControlador.eventoSelecionado.titulo}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{messages.inicio}" />  
                <h:outputText value="#{monitorarEventoControlador.eventoSelecionado.inicio}" />  

                <h:outputText value="#{messages.gravidade}" />  
                <h:outputText value="#{monitorarEventoControlador.eventoSelecionado.gravidade}" />  
            </p:panelGrid>
            <p:dataTable id="tableComentario" var="comentario" value="#{monitorarEventoControlador.eventoSelecionado.getComentariosAsList()}" emptyMessage="#{messages.noRecordsFound}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    #{messages.comentarios}
                </f:facet>
                <p:column headerText="#{messages.dataHora}"> 
                    <h:outputText value="#{comentario.dataHora}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" timeZone="#{monitorarEventoControlador.buscaTimeZone()}"/>
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>  
                <p:column headerText="#{messages.usuario}"> 
                    <h:outputText value="#{comentario.usuario.orgao.sigla} - #{comentario.usuario.apelido}"/>
                </p:column>  
                <p:column headerText="#{messages.texto}"> 
                    <h:outputText value="#{comentario.texto}" />  
                </p:column>  
            </p:dataTable>
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 100%">
                <h:inputText value="#{monitorarEventoControlador.comentarioSelecionado.texto}" maxlength="80"/>
                <p:commandButton value="#{messages.comentar}" actionListener="#{monitorarEventoControlador.adicionarComentario()}" icon="ui-icon-check" update="tableComentario" />
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

**And the bean:**

```
    public void adicionarComentario() {
        comentarioSelecionado.setDataHora(new Date());
        comentarioSelecionado.setEvento(eventoSelecionado);
        comentarioSelecionado.setUsuario(autenticador.getUsuarioCorrente());
        todosOsComentarios.colocar(comentarioSelecionado);
        notificarComentario(comentarioSelecionado);
        eventoSelecionado.getComentarios().add(comentarioSelecionado);
        todosOsEventos.colocar(eventoSelecionado);
        iniciarComentario(eventoSelecionado);
    }

 private void notificarComentario(Comentario comentario) {
    Notificacao n = new Notificacao();
    n.setDataHora(comentario.getDataHora());
    n.setDescricao(DateUtil.dataHoraFormatada(n.getDataHora()) + " - " + comentario.getUsuario().getOrgao().getSigla() + "(" + comentario.getUsuario().getApelido() + "): " + comentario.getTexto());
    n.setComentario(true);
    n.setInforme(comentario.getEvento().getInforme());
    comentario.getEvento().getInforme().getNotificacoes().add(n);
}

public void iniciarComentario(Evento evento) {
    comentarioSelecionado = new Comentario();
    setEventoSelecionado(evento);
}
```

The commandButton should update a dataTable. I have just moved from Prime 3.5 to 5.1 and among other problems I managed to figure out, there is this one that's realy annoying. It was working on Prime 3.5.
To be more specific about what is going wrong here: The action is fired normaly, the data is inserted correctly, but the dataTable is no longer updated. It is the very same code I was using yesterday with Prime 3.5, but now, using Prime 5.1 the dataTable does not refresh anymore.
Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: try adding process='@this' do commandButton

Comment: @LuísSoares `@this` is default. He should rather try to process the actual input text.  @Maverick_Java. Please show your bean as well, and specify the "Not working" - Error? Exception? What does Step-by-Step Debugging tell you?

Comment: isn't @form the default? I solved it like that, I believe. I also had to update from 3.1 to 5.1

Comment: @Maverick_Java When you place a breakpoint into the listener - is it triggered?

Comment: Hi, thanks. By "not working" I mean that the dataTable does not get updated. No errors, just nothing happens. I've already tried @this without success. To be more specific about what is going wrong here: The action is fired normaly, the data is inserted correctly, but the dataTable is no longer updated. It is the very same code I was using yesterday with Prime 3.5, but now, using Prime 5.1 the dataTable does not refresh anymore

Comment: can you provide some bean code? especially `adicionarComentario()` and `monitorarEventoControlador.comentarioSelecionado.texto`, and the part where `commentarioSelecionado` is loaded`?

Comment: Thanks @dognose. I've added some more code to the post. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong directly, but my phone screen might cover things due to a small font.  But instead of code snippets, can you create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so tgat it easier to reproduce. And are you sure there are no network/ajax errors in the browser developer tool or javascript errors?

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje. About your question, I see no errors. I'm realy lost here.

Comment: I am to if I do not have an mcve to try to reproduce

Comment: The button is inside a panel grid, while the table is outside that panel grid, so you need to point where is the component when you want to update it. Take a try: `update=":tableComentario"`. `:`means that the component is outside the current panel grid. As a long shot you could just try to update `@form`, it's not the best practice, but it's something.

Comment: Hi @Pellizon, I have already tried both, no luck.

Comment: Ok. I figured it out. I filled my code with try/catch and found that It was missing a value inside one of my Database tables. Although the values were being persisted and no exception were raised, there was one column without its value, it caused some Exception (without detail message or specific Exception Class, just "Exception") inside "notificarComentario" method. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

use **:** before id

---

**Remember**

if you make a dialog

1. Before dialog old form tag should be close
2. then dialog content should be placed into another form.
3. use :dialogid, :dialogFormId